# How to sum binary binomials in one command?

Tags: r, random, probability-density

I'd like to compact the creation of a vector `y` . It is the rowsum of some binary binomials with a probability each. With `rbinom()` I tried to define all probabilities at once but it doesn't give me what I want. Here I show the means, but most important to me are the PDFs.

```
set.seed(8659)
n <- 1e3

a <- rbinom(n, 1, .7)
b <- rbinom(n, 1, .6)
c <- rbinom(n, 1, .05)

df1 <- data.frame(a, b, c, y = a + b + c)
mean(df1$y)
# [1] 1.303

# failed attempt to do this in one command
y <- rbinom(n, 3, c(.7, .6, .05))
mean(y)
# [1] 1.376
```

Comment: `size` refers to the "number of trials" in the binomial distribution so changing this from 1 to 3 is sampling from a different distribution. Further, if you don't call `set.seed(8659)` prior to the second attempt of `rbinom` your results will never be replicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a vetor with the probabilities and loop over it and take the mean, i.e.

```
set.seed(8659)
n <- 1e3
mean(rowSums(sapply(c(.7, .6, .05), function(i) rbinom(n, 1, i))))
#[1] 1.303
```